# Application Temporarily Unavailable The URL http://xyz.com/test/ caused too many redirections

Tags: facebook, coldfusion

I am trying to get access_token via coldfusion. But when I write

```
<cflocation url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=12345678&redirect_uri=http://xyz.com/test/new/" addtoken="no">
```

I get the above error "Application Temporarily Unavailable The URL http://xyz.com/test/ caused too many redirections".. Plz help.. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you redirect to FB, which redirects back to you, which redirects to FB, which redirects to you.....

Try using a different launching page and landing page.

Comment: I am already using a different pages. Launching page: http://xyz.com/test/index.cfm. AND landing page(redirect_uri) is: http://xyz.com/test/new/index.cfm

Answer (score 0):

The error "...caused too many redirections" is a feature of modern browsers to prevent an infinite loop of redirection. Do a cflocation to a different location, or find a way to prevent the repeat colocation after Facebook redirects back to your page.

Comment: I am already using a different pages. Launching page: xyz.com/test/index.cfm. AND landing page(redirect_uri) is: xyz.com/test/new/index.cfm. Also, I should expect to get 'code' as url parameter,, right?

Comment: You'll have the post the code of both pages to get a meaningful answer. Your code has an infinite redirect loop in it somehow, but we can't help you because we can't see it.